# Run a script each time I login

Tags: login

I have a script to automatically connect to a server and want it to run each time I login with my user account. If possible make the script wait a few seconds to connect until the network can be connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 11 &&

<your_script> -c ~/.<your_scriptrc>
```

`#!/bin/bash` tells the computer you want it to do the following in bash, sleep 11 && tells the computer to wait 11 seconds

#### (increase or decrease the time as needed).

Answer (score 1):

this is a very basic example of the script

```
sleep 10
YOUR COMMAND HERE
```

what the sleep 10 does it waits for 10 seconds then it continues the script.
i don't know which commands your using to connect to a server so that part is up to you

go to the above right screen select startup
select add typ in a name and search where you saved the file and a comment if you like

you can also make it generate a log file like so
 
`YOUR COMMAND HERE>>serverlogin.log`
you can change it to where you want so save the log like so

```
YOUR COMMAND HERE>>/tmp/serverlogin.log
```